# Minimum Value of Reciprocal of Roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

If $f(x) = x^6+a_5x^5+...a_0$ be such that $f(0)=f(1)$ and each root of $f(x)=0$ is real and is between 0 and 1.Then find the minimum value of reciprocal of product of roots.

I tried to write $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{6}(x-x_{i})$ . Then with $f(0)=f(1)$ gives $\prod_{i=1}^{6}x_{i}=\prod_{i=1}^{6}(1-x_{i})$.I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore edited the question . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of minimizing product of reciprocal of roots, we will try to maximize $\prod\limits_{k=1}^6 x_k$.

We can safely assume all $x_k \in (0,1)$. This is because if any $x_k = 0$, then $\prod\limits_{k=1}^6 x_k = 0$ which is clearly not the maximum. Similiarly, if any $x_k = 1$, then $f(1) = 0 \implies \prod\limits_{k=1}^6 x_k = f(0) = 0$ which is again not we want.

For other configuration of $x_k$, we have

$$\prod_{k=1}^6 x_k = \prod_{k=1}^6 \sqrt{\frac{x_k}{1-x_k}}\sqrt{x_k(1-x_k)}$$
Notice for all $\lambda \in (0,1)$, we have $\sqrt{\lambda(1-\lambda)} \le \frac12$. This leads to

$$\prod_{k=1}^6 x_k \le \frac1{2^6}\prod_{k=1}^6\sqrt{\frac{x_k}{1-x_k}}
= \frac1{64}\sqrt{\frac{f(0)}{f(1)}} = \frac1{64}$$

This implies $a_0 = \prod\limits_{k=1}^6 x_k$ is bounded from above by $\frac{1}{64}$. Since this upper bounded is attained when all $x_k = \frac12$, we can
deduce the maximum value of $a_0$ is $\frac{1}{64}$. As a result,
the minimum value of product of reciprocals of roots is $64$.